# Does anyone know of a wrapper for the Addressbook framework for iphone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

Anyone know of a wrapper for the AddressBook framework that makes it a bit friendlier to use?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, Erica Sadun has developed an awesome Objective-C AddressBook wrapper framework.

I've personally used it in my projects, and I can attest that it works very well.

Check it out at [Github](http://github.com/erica/ABContactHelper).

Comment: @toby, this is the most updated version. I've already submitted an app to the App Store with this framework, so I think there's something else wrong.

Answer (score 7):

I recently completed a comprehensive iOS / iPhone wrapper framework that is available on GitHub. https://github.com/heardrwt/RHAddressBook

Comment: this one really is good by thread safety makes it really slow

Answer (score 3):

I know of two but have not used them.

1. [Google Toolbox for Mac](http://code.google.com/p/google-toolbox-for-mac/source/browse/#svn/trunk/iPhone)
2. [iPhoneContacts](http://github.com/AlanQuatermain/iPhoneContacts)

Answer (score 2):

I currently use [iPhoneContacts](http://github.com/AlanQuatermain/iPhoneContacts) and it works fine.