# Load iphone's addressbook db

Tags: iphone, ios4

Currenty I want to load iphone's addressbook db into my iphone app db..i mean i want to dump addressbook data into my app db

Is it possible? if so give me a link or references to do so

Thanks for any help

Cant i export AddressBook.sqlitedb to another sqlite db for my iphone app?

I mean, do i need to iterate over the loop?

Isn't possible to load the addressbook.db data into my database in which i am going to create my own addressbook ...

Comment: thanks for the reply. and is this a only way to load addressbook data into my app db?i mean do i need to iterate over the loop as above.isn't possible to load the addressbook.db data into my database...thanks for nay hel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it os possible.

Look here:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ContactData/Conceptual/AddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone/Introduction.html

It would like like that:

```
ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate( );
CFArrayRef allPeople = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople( addressBook );
CFIndex numberOfAllPeople = ABAddressBookGetPersonCount( addressBook );

for ( int i = 0; i < numberOfAllPeople; i++ )
{
ABRecordRef ref = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex( numberOfAllPeople, i );
//use the ref to store its properties in your db
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. and is this a only way to load addressbook data into my app db?i mean do i need to iterate over the loop as above.isn't possible to load the addressbook.db data into my database...thanks for nay help

Comment: I made an address book app called HiBye and I didn't find a way to clone all the addressbook. I recommend using CoreData for this.

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://zcentric.com/2008/09/19/access-the-address-book/) link may be useful to you.Thanks.
EDIT :
You need to search in some google links as well as the related posts on the same page. It would give you other ways around. Also as per your comment, you first of all need to fetch the data from the address book from any of the methods given in these different answers and store in NSDictionary or array and afterwards you can store it into your local database or web server using the supported methods. Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

This should have everything you need to get started:

[ABAddressBook Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/AddressBook/Reference/ABAddressBookRef_iPhoneOS/Reference/reference.html/)

The APIs are not meant to be used to dump the address book though - developers are supposed to interact with the centralized database in a courteous manner.

I recommend a full backup of your contact database before you start debugging ;)

Answer (score 0):

There is another Stackoverflow question which I posted a while ago that has some good answers that may be of some use to you.

- [Does anyone know of a wrapper for the Addressbook framework for iphone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3338542/does-anyone-know-of-a-wrapper-for-the-addressbook-framework-for-iphone)

However to answer your specific question as to whether you can export AddressBook.sqlitedb to your app, I think the answer is probably no.  You can achieve it via the AB Wrapper,but not by direct copying.